# How to put this into a loop?

Tags: java

I have been thinking about this problem for a few hours now, but can't seem to find a working solution.

I have this piece of code, which could theoretically be infinitely long:

```
y(1) = x(1)*h(1);
y(2) = x(1)*h(2)+x(2)*h(1);
y(3) = x(1)*h(3)+x(2)*h(2)+x(3)*h(1);
y(4) = x(1)*h(4)+x(2)*h(3)+x(3)*h(2)+x(4)*h(1);
y(5) = x(1)*h(5)+x(2)*h(4)+x(3)*h(3)+x(4)*h(2)+x(5)*h(1);
y(6) =           x(2)*h(5)+x(3)*h(4)+x(4)*h(3)+x(5)*h(2)+x(6)*h(1);
y(7) =                     x(3)*h(5)+x(4)*h(4)+x(5)*h(3)+x(6)*h(2);
y(8) =                               x(4)*h(5)+x(5)*h(4)+x(6)*h(3);
y(9) =                                         x(5)*h(5)+x(6)*h(4);
y(10) =                                                  x(6)*h(5);
```

To minimize the write effort and make it universally applicable, I want to put it in (probably?) two loops, but I don't know how. Maybe two for-loops with dynamically calculated variables? But then again I don't know how to pull it off.

Comment: Well, what is the formula in the general case? What happens if you have y(1) to y(11)? Suddenly you have an odd number of lines.

Comment: Y(i) will be your outermost loop and H the inner loop. Simply have the X variable calculate inside the H loop.

Comment: Does the x index simply move up after the halfway point for the y index? Or is it a fixed value of 5, for instance? Without the general algorithm, it's not possible to give a generic answer to this problem. However, if you only need it solved for y indexed from 1 to 10, then it may be possible to give an answer. Please advise on this.

Comment: Both h and x have a "maximum" of 5. Hard to describe :/. But I got good answers anyway :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fun to solve!

Note tested it, and seemed to work fine. With the x and h i used, My results are:
y(1) = 6

y(2) = 17

y(3) = 34

y(4) = 58

y(5) = 90

y(6) = 115

y(7) = 116

y(8) = 106

y(9) = 84

y(10) = 49

```
void DoCalcs () {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int result = Y (i);
    }
}


int Y (int i) {
    //calculate start index for x
    int xIndex = Math.Max (1, i - 4);

    //calculate end index for x
    int endXIndex = Math.Min (6, i);

    //running sum
    int totalresult = 0;

    //loop through h until reaches zero, or until we run out terms in the sum
    for (int startHIndex = Math.Min (5, i); startHIndex >= 1; startHIndex--) {
        totalresult += X (xIndex) * H (startHIndex);
        xIndex++;

        //if we run out of terms, break out and return result
        if (xIndex > endXIndex) {
            return totalresult;
        }

    }
    //otherwise return error
    return -9999;
}


int X (int i) {
    return i + 1;
    //this could be whatever
}

int H (int i) {
    return i + 2;
    //this could be whatever
}
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT: 
IF you need to have it continue to infinity, just remove the breakout return statement, and return the total at the end.**

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this while size is your dynamic size

```
    Double[] yArray = new Double[sizw];

      for(int i=0;i < yArray.length-4;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
            yArray[i+j] = x(i+1)*h(j+1);
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using C#.

```
for(int loop=1;loop<=10;loop++) {
  y[loop] = get_y[loop];
}
int get_y(int index) {
  int ret = 0;
  for(int loop=1;loop<=index) {
    ret += x[loop]*h[index-loop+1];
   }
   return ret;
 }
```